# Python - Find patterns through a sequence of 0's and 1's

Tags: python, arrays, artificial-intelligence, sequence

I'm working on a AI project using python which fills an array with 0's and 1's based on the user's input and predicts the next input based on the sequence of 0's and 1's. Are there any ways I can find a pattern in an array like this with random inputs and how much more accurate would it be over 100 or even 200 inputs from the user?

## EDIT:

It was recommended that I add some code. I haven't got much done on the main file:

```
print("Welcome AI Project V:0.1a\n")

username = ""

with open("./user.txt", "r+") as f:
    name = f.readline()
    name.rstrip('\n')
    if (name != ""):
        username = name
    else:
        name = input("Look's like you're new! What's your name?\n")
        f.write(name)
        username = name

    f.close()

feeling = input("Hello {0}! How are you today?\n".format(username))
with open("./feeling.neuron", "w") as file:
    file.write(changeTo0or1(feeling))


def changeTo0or1(string):
    # Will ask user whether feeling is good or bad but I feel it's easier to work with a file of 0's and 1's as it means there are only 2 possible outputs
```

Comment: This is a string input? When you ask a question it's always a good idea to include some code showing roughly what you are trying to achieve. Code speaks much clearer than words.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you are trying to predict whether a person feels good or bad based on his or her previous moods. And you want to convert this into a string of 1s (good) and 0s (bad) since the input is always binary.

```
user_mood_history = '000001100000110010011'
```

If for instance your user has a history of inputs as shown above in the variable `user_mood_history`, you are trying to predict the mood for the next input or day. If I look at the string, and if we started on a monday and got input every day, this person is rather happy during the weekends and very unhappy during the week.

I understand that it is not this clear generally, but let's say it is for now.

If you want to predict the user's mood the next day, which can be quite difficult from just a binary string, you can use some kind of machine learning algorithm, but be careful, it seems that you have little data points (inputs). Thus use a suitable machine learning algorithm.

Some idea's:

- Start of with a simple logistic regression model from [sklean LR](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)
- Hidden Markov Model
- Recurrent neural network (although I do not advice this due to the lack of data)
- ARIMA (Auto-regressive Integrated Moving Average, which can also prove to be too complicated for the simple task at hand)
- Random Forest classifier (take a look at [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)'s page)
- If you are a somewhat more advanced programmer, perhaps take a look at Prophet, Facebook's new time series modeling algorithm. [Prophet Github](https://github.com/facebookincubator/prophet)